# Call server side function using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Ultimately, I'd like to send a value to the server on a button click and query my DB.  For now, I'm having trouble using jquery.ajax to call a function on the server side.  Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ajax.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.ajax" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    if (jQuery) { alert("jQuery loaded"); }

    function send() 
    {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "get",
                url: "ajax.aspx/Test",
                data: { name: 'ok' },
                success: function (result) { alert("successful!"); }
            })
    }

  </script>
  <input type="button" runat="server" value="TryMe" onclick="send()" />
</asp:Content>

[WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static string Test(string sendData)
    {
        return String.Format("Hello {0}", sendData);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ this link could be usefull

EDIT: your ajax call have to look like this:

```
 $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "ajax.aspx/Test",
                data: "{ sendData: 'ok' }",
                success: function (result) { alert("successful!"); }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things which are not quite correct:

- You should put your data inside quotes
- and the name of the member should match the name of the web method's parameter
- the value for sendData should be in double quotes
- you should add contentType and dataType

Full example:

```
function send() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.aspx/Test",
        data: '{ sendData: "ok" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) { alert("successful!" + result.d); }
    });
}
```

This code works for me.