# Ajax - Return html page - on load function of that page not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have one ajax call which return entire html page.

Now that html page have one function which execute on page load event.

But when i am calling it via ajax it is not executing but when I call it via browser it is executing.

For example ,

In browser www.abc.com/test/test1 (Load jquery function on load)

In ajax call www.abc.com/test/test1 (Not load jquery function)

I want to execute that function via ajax call.

Ajax call

```
function test(str)
        {
            var $ajaxJQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
            console.log("insidee test");
            console.log(str);
            var $ajaxJQuery = jQuery.noConflict();          
             $ajaxJQuery.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url: "http://www.test.com/test/test-1",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);

                    //$ajaxJQuery("#Micrositecontainer").html(data);
                    $ajaxJQuery('body').html(data);     
                    //window.location = str;
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("err");
                    top.location = '${appBaseUrl}/'+responseUrl;
                }
            });
        }
```

Following is html page :=

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/general/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<title>Test 1</title>

<script>

            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            var locationDialogOpenFirstTime = true;
            var isTextChange = false;
            var inValidResult = 0;


            function getAllComponent(){
                    //  getCKHeaderdata();

                    var hideLocSession=''
                    if(hideLocSession=='Edit')
                    {
                        if(document.getElementById('hideLocation')!= null)
                            document.getElementById('hideLocation').className='usernameActive';
                    }
                    else if(hideLocSession=='Hide'){
                        if(document.getElementById('hideLocation')!= null)
                            document.getElementById('hideLocation').className='';
                    }
                    if(hideLocSession != null && hideLocSession!='' && hideLocSession != ' ' && hideLocSession != 'null' )
                    {
                        if(hideLocSession=='Edit')
                        {
                            $j("#showhideheader").toggle();
                            $j("#showhideTopNav").toggle();
                            $j("#showhideleft").toggle();
                            $j("#showhideRight").toggle();
                            $j("#hideshowMiddle").toggle();
                            $j("#showhideFooter").toggle();
                            $j("#sortIcon").toggle();
                        }
                    }


                         drawTreexmlTreeFoldersObj('&frmLeftTree=1');
                        drawTreexmlTreeOrphanObj();
                            getCommentOnload();

            }

</script>
</head>
<body  class="bodyimage bodyimage3 systemheaderBody" onload="getAllComponent()">
// some content is here
</body>
</html>
```

Now getAllComponent() is not loading when i call this page via ajax but execute when i opened this page via browser

Comment: Post your ajax call function please and how are you sending the ajax call.HTML/JS will help

Comment: it seems you are not calling the test() method anywhere and also you have not linked to jquery library in the above markup . What does the browser console show?

Comment: Jquery liberary is linked with the page from where i am calling test(). I have not put the page from where i call test(). The page you are seeing is actually a response of that url.

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032752/call-server-side-function-using-ajax

Comment: response is from the AJAX call?

Comment: Try to call body onload function " getAllComponent() " in script tag of your html page.

Comment: Yes , entire HTML page is response of the ajax call.

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681072/executing-a-javascript-function-returned-from-ajax-response-php

Comment: you can call the function in your ajax callback after the response html has been inserted wherever you want to insert it.