# Why I couldn't receive response from server

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I'm building a simple Login/Signup system using ExpressJS,Ajax and MongoDB
I'm currently stuck on the signup part, I want whenever a user click the signup button the email,account and password are sent back to the server, then server gonna check if that account is already exists or not and do the create user part.

```
                    if(psw===pswRe) 
            {
                // send uname psw and email to server;
                var user = '' + 'uname=' + window.encodeURIComponent(uname) + '&psw=' + window.encodeURIComponent(psw) + '&email=' + window.encodeURIComponent(email);
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                console.log(user);
                xhttp.open('POST','/signup',true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhttp.send(user);
                xhttp.onreadystagechange = function() {
                    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                        console.log(this.responseText);
                    }
                    if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==100) {
                        console.log(this.responseText);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is the problem, the server-side received the user but then its responses doesn't invoke the 'onreadystagechange' function in the client side so basically nothing is show up in the client's console.
Here is my server side code:

```
    app.post('/signup',(req,res)=> {
User.findOne({$or:[{username:req.body.uname},{email:req.body.email}]},function(err,result){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(result==null)
    {
        var userData = {
            username:req.body.uname,
            password:req.body.psw,
            email:req.body.email
        }
        User.create(userData,function(err,user) {
            if (err) 
                throw err;
            console.log('account created');
        })
        res.sendStatus(100);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('username already exists');
        res.sendStatus(201);
    }
})
    });
```

Comment: Try refering here for easier or better performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033128/10941112 or use **AngularJs** or **jQuery** for much better results

Comment: Change Content Type : application/json, if it helps :)

Comment: Also trying doing onreadystatechange()  before open()

Comment: Well, for starters, if any of your database calls have an error, you don't send ANY response.  Basically, you don't have any error handling in your server route handler.  `throw err` into an asynchronous callback does nothing useful.